# vue-resource returning a PromiseObj

Tags: javascript, promise, vue.js, vue-resource

How to I access the response data within an Ajax call? If I log `response.text()` it shows me a `PromiseObj`.

**Console**

```
PromiseObj
  context: undefined
  promise: Promise {status: "resolved", result: ")]}',↵{\"Result\":\"SUCCESS\",\"Data\":{\"mode\":\"DEV\"}}"}
```

**Code**

```
this.$http.post(endpoint, data, []).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.text());
}, (response) => {
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.json());
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `response.text().then(console.log)`? (possibly `.promise.then`, not sure what this "PromiseObj" is about). That's how promises are supposed to be used at least.

Comment: `response.text().then(console.log)` worked! Leave it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promise result values are supposed to be consumed using the `then` method:

```
response.text().then(console.log)
```

You can simplify your code by returning that promise and chaining onto it:

```
this.$http.post(endpoint, data, []).then(response => {
    console.log(response.status);
    return response.text();
}, response => {
    console.log(response.status);
    return response.json();
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
```